# Find specific expression between construction

Tags: regex

There are many lines like `alt="some-alt-text"` in my file. I need to replace dashes by white spaces.

Using Sublime I decided to find this string and replace dashes with regexp. 
I found expression like this `(?<=This is)(.*)(?=sentence)`. But how can i specify dashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `\K` (match reset) and `\G` (continous matching) to achieve this. With `(?:alt="|(?!^)\G)[^"-]+\K-` you can find all the dashes and then simply replace by  .